# How do I resolve the installer error "The configuration data for this product is corrupt."

Tags: installation, uninstall, windows-installer

The story goes something like this... A laptop is brought to me with VPN problems. Some techs already tried some things so not sure how it started but when I run the installer to do anything, repair, uninstall, it pops up with a dialogue box that tells me "The configuration data for this product is corrupt."

Now the techs who had it before me tried uninstalling it with Windows uninstall but that didn't work so they got into the registry and folder directory to clear out anything related to cisco anyconnect. I can run the installer for a newer version but it stops and says "The older version of Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client cannot be removed."

So I have a users laptop that needs VPN but I can't install a new version because it detects an old version that by all rights shouldn't be on the computer.

What can be done to get this PC to a point that it will completely uninstall the VPN so I can install an updated version?

Comment: They missed someting in the registry would be my guess.

Comment: When you say "with Windows uninstall", what precisely does that mean? Did they use the [Windows installer clean up utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.utilityspotlight.aspx), msizap, or something else? Have you made an [installer log](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545723) and looked at it?

Comment: I was referring to the programs utility in control panel. We have tried the Windows installer clean up utility but it can't find the cisco program. When I click my program is not listed it asks for like a 32 character software key that I do not know. I'll look into the installer log. I have not tried that yet.

Comment: David Schwartz, you're my hero. I had never heard of the installer log before. It pointed me to the exact registry key that was giving an error. The key was missed because it didn't reference cisco or anyconnect in any way, which was part of the problem, it was missing the 'packagename' string. It was probably partially deleted by coworkers. The VPN is installed and the problem is resolved. And I thought I was going to have to reinstall windows...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David Schwartz suggestion I used the installer log to identify where the old installer was running into problems. It directed me to a registry key that had the 'packagename' and value removed. I deleted the entire key and was able to install the vpn client.